# Flutter persistent sidebar

Tags: flutter, dart, sidebar, navigator

In my application I want to have a sidebar that allows me to have access to specific functions everywhere in my application.

---

***What I want :***

- That the sidebar remains visible when I push my pages
- That I can pushNamed route or open a modal with one of the sidebar functions
- That I can not display the sidebar on certain pages

---

***What I do :***

[image]

In red, the persistent `sidebar` and in yellow my `app content`.

[image]

If I click on my `profil button` in the `HomeView`, the `ProfilView` is displayed and my sidebar remains visible so it's ok

[image]

My `AppView` :

```
class AppView extends StatelessWidget {
  const AppView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      title: AppConfig.kAppName,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: AppTheme().data,
      builder: (context, child) => SidebarTemplate(child: child), // => I create a template 
      onGenerateRoute: RouterClass.generate,
      initialRoute: RouterName.kHome,
    );
  }
```

My `SidebarTemplate` : (Display the sidebar and load the page with my router)

```
class SidebarTemplate extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget? child;
  const SidebarTemplate({Key? key, this.child}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body : Row(
          children: [
            SidebarAtom(), // => My sidebar Widget
            Expanded(
              child: ClipRect(
                  child: child! // => My view
              ),
            )
          ],
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My `RouterClass` :

```
abstract class RouterClass{

  static Route<dynamic> generate(RouteSettings settings){
    final args = settings.arguments;

    switch(settings.name){

      case RouterName.kHome:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => HomeView()
        );

      case RouterName.kProfil:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => ProfilView(title: "Profil",)
        );

      default:
        return MaterialPageRoute(
            builder: (context) => Error404View(title: "Erreur")
        );
    }
  }
}
```

---

***How to do :***

- To pushNamed or open a modal with a button from my sidebar because I have an error

```
The following assertion was thrown while handling a gesture:
I/flutter (28519): Navigator operation requested with a context that does not include a Navigator.
I/flutter (28519): The context used to push or pop routes from the Navigator must be that of a widget that is a
I/flutter (28519): descendant of a Navigator widget.
```

- To hide the sidebar when I want like `SplashScreen` for example

**Any guidance on the best way to accomplish this would be appreciated.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `NavigatorObserver` to listen to the changes in the route.

```dart
class MyNavObserver with NavigatorObserver {
  final StreamController<int> streamController;

  MyNavObserver({required this.streamController});

  @override
  void didPop(Route route, Route? previousRoute) {
    if (previousRoute != null) {
      if (previousRoute.settings.name == null) {
        streamController.add(3);
      } else {
        streamController
            .add(int.parse(previousRoute.settings.name!.split('/').last));
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  void didPush(Route route, Route? previousRoute) {
    if (route.settings.name == null) {
      streamController.add(3);
    } else {
      streamController.add(int.parse(route.settings.name!.split('/').last));
    }
  }
}
```

and using  `StreamController` you can make changes to your `SidebarTemplate` by putting it inside `StreamBuilder`. This will take care of all the requirements you have mentioned in the question.

Check out the live example [here](https://dartpad.dev/?id=cad33684762405d04903180c51fbd805).

Answer (score 0):

As you can see from the `Profil` screenshot, the sidebar is not part of the widget subtree of the `Navigator` (the back button is only on the profil widget). This means that you cannot find the `Navigator` from the `context` of the sidebar. That is happening because you are using `builder` in your `MaterialApp` which [inserts widgets above the navigator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MaterialApp/builder.html).

That is also the reason why you cannot hide the sidebar when you want to show a splash screen.

Do you really need to use the `builder` on `MaterialApp`? Then you can save the Navigator globally and access it from the sidebar. [This is the first article when I search on DuckDuckGo](https://medium.com/flutter-community/navigate-without-context-in-flutter-with-a-navigation-service-e6d76e880c1c), that you can follow.

To show a SplashScreen you would need to add a state to `AppView` and change the `builder` function. Not very nice if you ask me.

I suggest you to re-think your architecture and get rid of the `builder` in the `MaterialApp`.